# Find nodeList nested <span>

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, jquery-selectors, telegram-bot, nodelist

I'm trying to web-scrape **for the first time** in order to get the best deal out of my holiday.

*(My intention is to have a Telegram Bot that everyday checks a specific day in the hotel calendar and sends me a notification)*

This calendar that has this specific HTML structure (see pic for reference) [image: html day] and what I'm tryng to get is the price of a specific day. So then I can later make something that checks the website daily (8:05 am) and send me a notification.

This also could be a nice project for my portfolio and not only a way to get the best deal as I'm always broke.

This is what my code looks like

`document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="mar 31 ott 2023"]')`

to get the specific day and as a result in the logs I get this (see pic) [image]

How can I get only the price that has this html structure `<span><strong>999€</strong></span>` ?

In the console output it is under the `innerText`. (alongide the day)

I hope I have been enough clear in what I need help with

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="mar 31 ott 2023"]')].map(div => div.querySelector('strong').textContent)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run querySelector method once again on the node that you need. Something like this

```
document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="mar 31 ott 2023"]')[0].querySelector('strong').innerText
```